# In LINQ, how can I do an .OrderBy() on data that came from my .Include()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here's what I'm doing:

```
List<Category> categories = 
  db.Categories.Include("SubCategories").OrderBy(c => c.Order).ToList();
```

I have a column on my categories table called "Order" which simply holds an integer that gives the table some kind of sorting order.

I have the same column on my "SubCategories" table...

I want to know the simplest solution to add the sort on my subcategories table... something like:

```
List<Category> categories = 
  db.Categories.Include("SubCategories").OrderBy(c => c.Order)
     .ThenBy(c => c.SubCategories as x => x.Order).ToList();
```

I'd like to keep it in this type of LINQ format... (method format)...

Keep in mind, i'm working in MVC and need to return it to a view as a model.  I've been having trouble with errors because of AnonymousTypes...

Comment: Is `Category.SubCategories` a collection or an instance? That is, are there many sub categories or is it just one? It looks like a collection based on the name, but if this is the case, then you'll need to use an aggregation function (e.g. Min/Max/Average) in your `ThenBy`.

Comment: Yes, it's a collection.  There are many subcategories under one category... and these are stored in 2 separate tables with a foreign key from the subcat to the cat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the single query into 2 queries which just fill up the context:

```
IQueryable<Category> categoryQuery = db.Categories.Where(c=> /*if needed*/);
List<Category> categories = categoryQuery.OrderBy(c => c.Order).ToList();
categoryQuery.SelectMany(c => c.SubCategories)
  .OrderBy(sub => sub.Order)
  .AsEnumerable().Count(); // will just iterate (and add to context) all results
```

You even don't need the error prone string "SubCategories" anymore then.

Comment: This would order the SubCategories when taken as a whole, rather than considering their relevance to each Category, no?

Comment: This will work fine, the SubCategories are just attached in this order by the context to its parent so for each parent its subcategories are sorted by Order property. This of course only works side-effect free on a fresh context -- but EF contexts always should be short-living. But thinking about it, it would be safer to fill the categories list **first** and do the `SelectMany` query after this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is supported, but here's how it might be done:

```
List<Category> categories = 
  db.Categories.Include(c => c.SubCategories.OrderBy(s => s.Order)).OrderBy(c => c.Order)
```

The `Include` method now supports Expressions like this, but I'm not certain if it supports ordering too.

You might be better off sorting the subcategories when you use them, probably in your view.

For example:

```
@for (var cat in Model.Categories) {
   @cat.Name
   @for (var sub in cat.SubCategories.OrderBy(c => c.Order) {
       @sub.Name
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Category.SubCategories` is a collection in itself, then you won't be able to order using the existing extension methods (and `c => c.SubCategories as x => x.Order` translates to almost nothing, basically saying that `SubCategories` is a `Func<SubCategory, bool>`)

If you're content to have the sorting done in memory (which shouldn't really be a problem since you're already fetching them from the database anyway, provided you don't have thousands of the things) you can implement your own custom `IComparer<Category>` which interrogates the `SubCategories` of each `Category` to determine whether one `Category` should be placed above or below another `Category` in a sort operation.

Your statement would then be:

```
var categories = db.Categories.Include("SubCategories").OrderBy(x => x, new CategorySubCategoryComparer())
```

Comment: You can't use `CategorySubCategoryComparer` in linq2entity or linq2sql

Comment: Based on the usage of Include, my assumption was that the OP is using the Entity Framework (although it's not specified). You can use a custom IComparer<T> with any IEnumerable. If Entity Framework isn't smart enough to execute the query before passing to the overload of OrderBy that accepts a custom IComparer, then the OP can execute the following instead: var categories = db.Categories.Include("SubCategories").ToList().OrderBy(x => x, new CategorySubCategoryComparer())

Comment: Yes EF is not smart, in fact, EF can't convert this to expression tree to make sql query from that, so first should execute it, and in this case is not very bad but is not very good.

Comment: I was in no doubt that any ORM, EF or not, could interpret a custom IComparable<T> and convert it into SQL :)