# In LINQ, how can I do an .OrderBy() on data that came from many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, include, many-to-many

I have already seen the answers to these questions [In LINQ, how can I do an .OrderBy() on data that came from my .Include()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158939/in-linq-how-can-i-do-an-orderby-on-data-that-came-from-my-include), [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848787/trying-to-order-by-value-that-has-a-one-to-many-relationship-linq-query) and [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477389/order-by-with-linq-include), However, None is the answer to my question.

I have three entities: Letter, Person, LetterPerson as follows:

```
public class Letter
{
    public int LetterId { get; set; }
    public string  Title { get; set; }

    //MtoM
    public ICollection<LetterPerson> LetterPersons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    //MtoM
    public ICollection<LetterPerson> LetterPersons { get; set; }
}

    public class LetterPerson
{
    public int LetterPersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Letter")]
    public int LetterId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? AssignDate { get; set; }=DateTimeOffset.Now;
    public Letter Letter { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

The `Letter` entity has `Many To Many` relationship with the `Person` entity by the `LetterPerson` entity. Now, I'd like to get a list of the person according to a specific letter's id and order by on the `LetterPerson`'s id.

I have something like the following query in mind:

```
var PersonRec = await _dbContext.Persons
                    .Include(u => u.LetterPersons)
                    .Where(u => u.LetterPersons.Any(i => i.LetterId == LetterId))
                    .OrderBy(u => u.LetterPersons.LetterPersonId)
                    //.Include(u => u.LetterPersons.OrderBy(f=>f.LetterPersonId))
                    //.Where(u => u.LetterPersons.OrderBy(f=>f.LetterPersonId).Any(i => i.LetterId == LetterId))
                    //.OrderBy(u => u.LetterPersons.FirstOrDefault().LetterPersonId)
                    .ProjectTo<PersonDTO>(_mapperConfiguration).ToListAsync();
```

The above commented codes are the attempts that I made, but still the desired result was not achieved. I need `.OrderBy(u => u.LetterPersons.LetterPersonId)` , However, it clearly gives a [compile error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)).

**Question:**
How should I correct the `OrderBy` part?

Just note that I have to send the query as a `Data Transfer Object` (`PersonDTO`) that the same as `Person` entity except `FirstName` field.

I use EF6 in .Net6.

Comment: Likewise you do in SQL, Join/Include first, Filter/Where second, Grouping third and Sorting last.

Comment: Each `Person` has multiple `LetterPerson` and `Letter` entities related. What is it that you actually want to sort on? You haven't actually explained that. Is it, for instance, by the greatest `LetterPersonId` value? I think that would be something like `.OrderBy(p => p.LetterPersons.Select(lp => lp.LetterPersonId).Max())`.

Comment: `What is it that you actually want to sort on? ` I'd like to display a list of person in a specific letter in the order they were assigned to the letter.

Comment: C# is a language of types. What is the type of `LetterPerson`? Does that type have a property or field named `LetterPersonId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the combination `(LetterId, PersonId)` is unique in the joining table (typical for many-to-many), then the one-to-many relation from `Person` to `LetterPerson` for specific `LetterId` value becomes one-to-one, hence you can use `Select` or `SelectMany` with filter to get the single `LetterPerson` entry, which then could be used for ordering.

For isntance, using LINQ query syntax (more natural for such type of queries):

```cs
var query =
(
    from p in _dbContext.Persons
    from lp in p.LetterPersons
    where lp.LetterId == LetterId
    orderby lp.LetterPersonId
    select p
)
.ProjectTo<PersonDTO>(_mapperConfiguration);

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Note that you don't need `Include` in order to access related data inside LINQ to Entities query. Also for projection queries `Include`s are ignored.

Comment: `Note that you don't need Include in order to access related data inside LINQ to Entities query. Also for projection queries Includes are ignored.`    Could you explain more please?

Comment: Does your query cause any performance issues?

Comment: @AlirezaK (1) You can access navigation properties and their nested properties inside a query, and EF Core will translate them to appropriate SQL `inner' or `left` joins to the corresponding tables (2) I don't expect such, since it should generate simple inner join of the two tables.